# Android remove Progress Dialog focus and make gridview under it focusable?

Tags: android

Hello i'm developing an Android app. When app start images start loading in gridview. And when user scroll the gridview and reach bottom, a progress dialog show.
But it take all focus and prevent the gridview to scroll till new data doesn't load.
I want scrolling enabled when progressbar showing...
Please help me....

Comment: a dialog or an alertdialog is made to take the "focus"... that's that it's used for. If you want another behavior you should use a custom view

Comment: yes i want to know about that property, with which i can remove it's focus....

Comment: You don't understand. You don't make a dialog lose it's focus, the only proper way is to dismiss it. If you want some loading effect that don't block the UI you should use Views !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lib https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh or write an overlay loading yourself